# detecting bind mounts on linux

Tags: c++, python, c, linux

I am looking for a way to determine if a given path is a bind mount point (on linux). The standard techniques for detecting regular mount points don't seem to work. Even the mountpoint command fails to detect bind mounts.

Comment: I really would like to understand the reason why you are asking such a  question.

Comment: It started out as something I thought I needed, and now its progressed into more of an "I just have to know".

The original reason was that I'm writing a rather comprehensive file-system walker/scanner.

Comment: Then you try to remember the inodes you already visited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure there is supposed to be a way to do that (except perhaps thru `/etc/mtab` or `/etc/fstab`) because I understand that bind mounts are sort-of "hard links" in the mount space (not the file hierarchy), and there is no way (once the bind mount happened) to distinguish the source and the target mount points.

And why are asking that? Bind mounts are (IMHO) mostly useful to *hide* such things from the application's point of view (otherwise you would use symlinks -or even hard links, in the rare cases they are possible- for directories)

And `mountpoint` which I just discovered thanks to your question seems to see something:

```
% grep /home /etc/fstab
UUID=000008-0003-000c-9ecd-0f1a /home           ext3    defaults        0       2
% grep /usr/src /etc/fstab
/home/Src /usr/src none bind 0 0
% mountpoint /usr/src
/usr/src is a mountpoint
% mountpoint /home/Src
/home/Src is not a mountpoint
```

By `strace`-ing `mountpoint` I find that it is doing `lstat`,`stat` and `fstat` syscalls on directories like `/usr/src` & `/usr/src/..`

---

<sup>(added in november 2016:)</sup>

See also `/proc/mounts` e.g. [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Comment: I believe the technique that mountpoint uses is to look for l/stat path and path/.., and then look for either different device id's or the same inode. As for the fstat call, that one i'm not sure about but it may not be directly related to the mountpoint check.

As for the 'why'. You make a good point about they are used for and I've decided to consider link mounts within the same device as regular directories. That being said, I am still curious as to how one detects them.
Currently the best technique i've found is to scan the /proc/mounts and /etc/mtab for the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a path is a mountpoint, by examining the device id of the path and of its parent (provided that the mounted filesystem is different to that of the parent directory - I've never tried bind-mounting a directory onto itself!).

Here's a quick command-line demonstration:

```sh
$ cut -d ' ' -f2 /proc/mounts | xargs stat -c '%d %n'
18 /sys
4 /proc
6 /dev
19 /dev/pts
20 /run
2049 /
7 /sys/kernel/security
21 /dev/shm
22 /run/lock
23 /sys/fs/cgroup
24 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
25 /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
26 /sys/fs/pstore
27 /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
28 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
29 /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
30 /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
31 /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
32 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
33 /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
34 /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
35 /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
39 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
17 /dev/mqueue
8 /sys/kernel/debug
37 /dev/hugepages
2066 /home
39 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
44 /run/user/1000
45 /sys/fs/fuse/connections
2049 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d
4 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/proc
18 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/sys
6 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/dev
19 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/dev/pts
2066 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/home
2049 /run/schroot/mount/my-chroot-cb43935e-0812-45ea-af4f-965a1e2de91d/tmp
```

Once you know it's a mountpoint, then if its device id is common to multiple entries in `/proc/mounts`, you can assume that one of them is a bind mount.  Finding out which one is the bind and which is the bound-to is still a missing piece from this answer.

N.B. `/proc/mounts` entries use octal escapes for some problematic characters, so a robust script will need to launder these through `printf %b` or similar.

Comment: I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

`findmnt` shows bind mounts:

```
$ grep /opt /home /etc/fstab
/home/admin/opt  /opt  none bind 0
LABEL=raidhome /home ext4 defaults,nodiratime,relatime 0       2

$ findmnt --fstab /opt
TARGET SOURCE          FSTYPE OPTIONS
/opt   /home/admin/opt none   bind


$ findmnt /opt
TARGET SOURCE               FSTYPE OPTIONS
/opt   /dev/md1[/admin/opt] ext4   rw,nodiratime,relatime,stripe=16

$ findmnt -J /opt
{
   "filesystems": [
      {
         "target": "/opt",
         "source": "/dev/md1[/admin/opt]",
         "fstype": "ext4",
         "options": "rw,nodiratime,relatime,stripe=16"
      }
   ]
}
```

Not exactly straightforward, but the information is there.

Answer (score -4):

```
$ mount | grep bind
```

i'm not very clear about what you want, is this command fit your need?

Comment: "mount" output does not identify bind mounts, at least in modern systems (2022).